# Swift: UISearchBar: Get text when search button clicked

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisearchbar

I'm playing around with Swift to learn it and right now I'm having trouble getting the text from a `UISearchBar`

Right now my code looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myWebView : UIWebView
    @IBOutlet var adressbar: UISearchBar

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        adressbar.showsScopeBar = true

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!) {

        var url = NSURL(string: adressbar.text)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the issue you are having? Is `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` being called? Should you be using `adressbar.text` instead of `searchbar.text`? I see no attempt in here to even touch the search bar.

Comment: searchBarSearchButtonClicked is not being called

Comment: Did you hook it's action up to that function in some way?

Comment: Probably not. how do i hook it's action to that function?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` you must set the delegate of the search bar to be receiving `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` from it:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var myWebView : UIWebView
    @IBOutlet var adressbar: UISearchBar

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        adressbar.showsScopeBar = true
        adressbar.delegate = self

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!)
    {
        var url = NSURL(string: searchBar.text)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple (non-specific) answer for those arriving here via search:

If your outlet name for your UISearchBar is 'searchBar'...

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Then the text entered by the user in UISearchBar is called...

```
searchBar.text
```

Two common things Swift coders forget:
1.  Make sure to add `UISearchBarDelegate` class...

```
ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate
```

2. Don't forget to identify your view class as the delegate...
   Inside `viewDidLoad` you could write...

   ```
   searchBar.delegate = self
   ```

If you forget #1 above you won't be able to auto-complete the methods you'll need to implement like...

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ seachBar: UISearchBar) { your code }
```

... which is given to you by the delegate protocol.

Answer (score 2):

1.First thing is to conform to the UISearchbarDelegate.

2.Set the search bar delegate to self.

You can find more on this here [Swift iOS tutorial : Implementing search using UISearchBar and UISearchBarDelegate](http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/02/16/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/)